# I found GetCheckedItems() function that is could know how items checked included child items in Tree Control

Tags: winapi, mfc

I know what is the shift and bit operator but what mean this code? I don't understand well.

Please explicate me very easy.

```
UINT state = (tree.GetItemState(item, TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK) >> 12) & 15;
```

Below is the original code:

```
 void GetCheckedItems(const CTreeCtrl& tree, CArray<HTREEITEM> 
                 *checkedItems, HTREEITEMstartItem=NULL)
 {
   if (startItem == NULL)
    startItem = tree.GetRootItem();

   for (HTREEITEM item = startItem; item != NULL; item = 
       tree.GetNextItem(item, TVGN_NEXT))
      {
      // figure out if this item is checked or not
      UINT state = (tree.GetItemState(item, TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK) >> 12) & 
      15; // i Wonder this (  shift and bit operator )

    if (state == 2)
    checkedItems->Add(item);

    // deal with children if present
    HTREEITEM child = tree.GetNextItem(item, TVGN_CHILD);

    if (child != NULL)
    GetCheckedItems(tree, checkedItems, child);
  }
}
```

Comment: This should help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/work-with-state-image-indexes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: `(state >> 12) & 15` moves bits 12 through 15 down to bits 0 through 3, and clears everything starting from bit 4 upwards.

In context of tree-view controls this is meaningful for application-defined image states. As explained under [Tree-View Item States Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tree-view-controls#tree-view-item-states-overview):

> A state image is displayed next to an item's icon to indicate an application-defined state. State images are contained in a *state image list* that is specified by sending a [TVM_SETIMAGELIST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tvm-setimagelist) message. To set an item's state image, include the [TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tree-view-control-item-states) value in the `statemask` member of the [TVITEM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-tvitema) structure. **Bits 12 through 15 of the structure's state member specify the index in the state image list of the image to be drawn**.

The check state of a tree-view control's item is stored in the item state. By convention, the image at index 0 requests no state image, index 1 is the unchecked state, and index 2 the checked state.

Masking out the state image index concerned with the check state of an item, and comparing it against the value 2 thus determines whether a tree-view item's state is checked.